# How &@ and &/@works?

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols

I have the following expression:

```
(Join[#, Reverse[#, {2}]] &@Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]) & /@ Vec
 
(* where: *)
Vec={{2,0},{1,1},{0,2}},
```

but I am not sure how this expression works. I tried

```
Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]) & /@ Vec,{0,2}}
```

and

```
Partition[Vec, 2, 1, 1])
```

but they gave me different results. I am not sure what # in the `Join[]` stands for (`Partition[]` or Vec).

In general, what is the logic behind this expression?

Comment: See also: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/43522)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the precedence of nested anonymous functions, the innermost expression:

```
Join[#, Reverse[#, {2}]] &
```

Is essentially identical to:

```
Function[{x}, Join[x, Reverse[x, {2}]]
```

Let's explicitly label this as function `f` using (yet another mostly equivalent notation):

```
f[x_] := Join[x, Reverse[x, {2}]]
```

So we can rewrite the original expression as:

```
(f@Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]) & /@ Vec
```

We can again rewrite the anonymous function, let's call it `g` this time:

```
g[x_] := f@Partition[x, 2, 1, 1]
```

(Or, equivalently: `f[Partition[x, 2, 1, 1]`, rewriting the `@` in perhaps more familiar terms.)

Then the expression becomes:

```
g /@ Vec
```

Which is exactly equivalent to: `Map[g, Vec]`.